oh-my-posh on bash, how can I display the current command history number
In bash, I can set my command prompt to be the current history number (PS1=\!). How can I do this with oh-my-posh? I know how to get the current prompt counter with {{ .PromptCount }}, but not the current history number.

To solve this problem, you need to override the set_poshcontext function. I put it at the end of my .bashrc as follows.
    eval "$(oh-my-posh init bash --config ~/history.omp.json)"
    function set_poshcontext() {
      export CURRENT_HISTORY_NUMBER=$(history -n ~/.bash_history; awk '{print $1}' < <(history 1))
    }
    export -f set_poshcontext

Make sure that the set_poshcontext() function is exported after the oh-my-posh init. Every time the prompt is formed, CURRENT_HISTORY_NUMBER is updated. It can then be used in the oh-my-posh config file as follows.
    {
      "type": "text",
      ...
      "template": "{{ .Env.CURRENT_HISTORY_NUMBER }}"
    }

Thanks to @diego for the bash code, which is used verbatim.

You can add a command like this
        {
           "type": "command",
           ...
           "properties": {
           "shell": "bash",
                "command": "history -n ~/.bash_history; awk '{print $1}' < <(history 1)"
            }
        }
...

as an oh-my-posh config.

awk command is run in a separate shell, so history outputs nothing.
